# How to check if a value inside a tensor is True

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor with some values, like `[10, 10, 5]`. I want to know if some of them are repeating among the tensor. So for that, I use this:

```
tf.unique_with_counts(
    tf.constant([10, 10, 5])
)[2] > 1
```

Which gives me the following values: `True, False` regarding of `10` is repeating and `5` not.

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=bool, numpy=array([ True, False])>
```

But how can, in a simplified way, check if within this array is there any `True` value? For now I have a loop but this isn't efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.reduce_any`, which performs a logical or:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

y = tf.reduce_any(tf.unique_with_counts(
    tf.constant([10, 10, 5]))[2] > 1)
print(y)
# tf.Tensor(True, shape=(), dtype=bool)
```